# Vuforia is not recognizing the image i show. Unity 3D 2018 last version

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I want to create the simplest AR program that anyone can do.I downloaded unity3d latest version with the implemented Vuforia (i checked the box to be included in the installation). I almost copied everything from a video i watched on Youtube, in the video the guy was showing everything step-by-step. At first when i was done when i was pressing the "play" button my camera wasn't turning on, then i did a research and found that it was a problem with 64-bit of unity (or so i think) then i updated the unity3d to latest version and my camera was turning on after the installation was finished. But, this time when i show the picture that i have on the database of vuforia (and downloaded / imported on unity3d afterwards) it does not recognize it, or i think i screwed up the AR that i wanted to show up. I want the picture to be replaced with another one when it recognizes it.

Now, first of all i got 5 stars on my picture on Vuforia's site before downloading the database.
I've put a Quad and a material inside of it with the same size as the database picture and the picture to be replaced with in the material.
Any help?

Comment: What is the type in your  `ImageTargetBehavior`script. Can you add a screenshot of it in the inspector.

Comment: What were the steps you took to configure your unity to connect your vuforia account/settings? Did you enter your key, etc?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Did you add an AR camera to the scene?

Comment: I did everything that’s nenecessary to invoke vuforia. I got a key i got database did the settings to enable vuforia . I didnt wrote any script. Just drag and drop.